# How to say "What does 'Wetter' mean"?

Tags: grammaticality

I know what *Wetter* means, I just need the sentence.

My friend said it was:

> Was bedeutet Wetter bedeuten.

I want to know if he was right or wrong, because I never put the *bedeuten* at the end. In case that's correct, could you tell me why and when they do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "because I never put the "bedeuten" also could you tell me why and when they do this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence "Was bedeutet Wetter bedeuten." does not make any sense to me.

Maybe you mean something like:

> Was bedeutet "Morgenrot kann schlechtes Wetter bedeuten"?

This could be translated to:

> What is the meaning of "A red sky in the morning indicates bad
>   weather"?

In this sentence the second "bedeuten" is "to indicate" or "to signify" or "to announce".

Comment: Die Antwort ist der Versuch zu klären was überhaupt die Frage ist. Sowas gehört in einen Kommentar - auch auf die Gefahr hin nicht der erste zu sein. Die Überschrift der Frage deutet darauf hin, dass Deine Interpretation falsch ist.

Comment: @Kentucky Fried Turkey: please clearify your question/expected answer. Was your question just shortened and simlified as I interpreted it or is it what RoyPJ and others wrote (then please move the best answer flag and I'll delete my answer if it's not useful)

Answer (score 7):

Considering the headline of this post i think you just wanted to know if your friend was right.
He was wrong, the correct translation is:

> Was bedeutet "Wetter"? ( = What does "wetter" mean? )

Answer (score 3):

The standard question looks like:

> Was bedeutet "*your word(s) here*"?

Only auxiliary verbs can appear twice in the same sentence... And maybe some modal verbs or some that have two different (and compatible) meanings.

Your friend's  version correspnds to "What does weather mean *random form of mean*?"

Comment: What means weather means?

Comment: @DisplayName Excuse me?

Comment: @DisplayName provided a literal translation for OPs sentence, more closely than "What does weather mean *random form of mean*".

Comment: @Em1 He is mistaken, since "What means xyz?" cannot be translated as "Was bedeutet xyz?" - mostly because it's wrong.

Comment: Well, correct would be "Would does xyz mean". That said, the German sentence is nonsense either; in this respect, this word-for-word translation is quite spot on.

Comment: Ex falso quodlibet...

Answer (score 1):

Wie RoyPJ sagt muss es

> Was bedeutet Wetter?

heißen, allerdings ohne Anführungsstriche die für wörtliche Rede verwendet werden oder Zitate, allenfalls noch in zweideutigen Situationen, wenn keine anderen Auszeichnungen wie Kursivschreibung zur Verfügung stehen. Hier besteht aber keine Schwierigkeit den Sinn des Satzes zu erfassen.

Es gibt aber auch Konstruktionen mit *Bedeuten* am Ende, und zwar wie aus dem bekannten Lied *Loreley* bekannt, *Ich weiß nicht, was soll es bedeuten*, also übertragen auf das Wort Wetter:

> Was soll *Wetter* bedeuten?